# Rotation of mdframed box

Tags: rotating, mdframed

I’d like to rotate a fancy box made with mdframed for a take home message on a poster. This is a MWE where rotatebox fails. Also tried package rotation with same effect. Left the minipage environment I’d like to use in the poster.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
Text
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\rotatebox{20}{
\begin{mdframed}
\large{Text}
\end{mdframed}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: since you are already loading `tcolorbox` why use `mdframed` at all? It is my impression that `tcolorbox` is vastly more powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work but you can use `\usepackage{rotating}` and `turn` environment instead.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{rotating}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
Text
\end{minipage}
\begin{turn}{56}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{mdframed}
\large{Text}
\end{mdframed}%

\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: turn-environment does’t work inside the minipage wrapping the mdframed-box, but since I don’t need this, this solution is fine for me

Answer (score 2):

I agree with daleif, just use tcolorbox:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    enhanced,
    width=.5\textwidth,
    tikz={rotate=15,transform shape}
]%
    Some fancy test.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: rotated box]

Comment: Probably a good idea but I have a fully specified mdframed-box at hand already and wanted to use it